# Pulling stock option data with python pandas - broke overnight

Tags: python, pandas

Last night I typed up the following

```
from pandas.io.data import Options
import csv

symList = []
optData = {}

with open('C:/optionstrade/symbols.txt') as symfile:
    symreader = csv.reader(symfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in symreader:
        symList = row

for symbol in symList:
    temp = Options(symbol,'yahoo')
    try:
        optData[symbol] = temp.get_all_data()
    except:
        pass
```

It worked alright.  I only got data from 200 something of the 400 something symbols I have in the file, but it pulled the options data for those 200 something just fine.

This morning, I go to run the code again (markets have been open for nearly an hour) and I get nothing:

```
In [6]: len(optData)
Out[6]: 0
```

So I run a bit of a test:

```
test = Options('AIG','yahoo')
spam = test.get_all_data()
import pickle
with open('C:/optionstrade/test.txt','w') as testfile:
    pickle.dump(test,testfile)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-902aa7c31f7e> in <module>()
      1 test = Options('AIG','yahoo')
----> 2 spam = test.get_all_data()

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.pyc in get_all_data(self, call, put)
   1109 
   1110             for month in months:
-> 1111                 m2 = month.month
   1112                 y2 = month.year
   1113 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'
```

And this content of the pickled file:

```
ccopy_reg
_reconstructor
p0
(cpandas.io.data
Options
p1
c__builtin__
object
p2
Ntp3
Rp4
(dp5
S'symbol'
p6
S'AIG'
p7
sb.
```

Nothing has changed overnight on my end... last thing I did was save and shut down.  First thing I did after waking up was run it again.

Comment: If you compare the HTML on the cached page: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=AIG versus the current page http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=AIG you'll see the format of the HTML has changed. There is no longer a `<table>` with a`id="yfncsumtab"` attribute, for instance. This is leading to a breakdown in the way the HTML was being parsed. Please post this as an issue on https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues.

Comment: An issue has been opened here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8612